# How to generate JWT Token and use into Oracle SCM Cloud

Tags: jwt, oracle-rest-data-services, oracle-cloud-functions

I need to use JWT Authorization in Oracle SCM Cloud .
For that I have generated Private Key and Public certificate.
Using Following Command

openssl genrsa -out scmnowtest.key 1024

openssl req -new -x509 -key scmnowtest.key -out scmnowtest.cer -days 365
I have also generated x5t using
echo $(openssl x509 -in scmnowtest.pem -fingerprint -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64

But when I am trying to generate JWT token from https://jwt.io/
it's giving invalid Signature Error.
Cab someone guide me
Thanks

Comment: Should the third command be "echo $(openssl x509 -in scmnowtest.cer -fingerprint -noout) | sed 's/SHA1 Fingerprint=//g' | sed 's/://g' | xxd -r -ps | base64"?

Catch is ".pem" vs ".cer"

Comment: @bmuthuv it works for both